# Unique key issue in solr

Tags: mysql, database, solr

In my solr index I have in each document:

```
tag_name
thread_name
```

I have no id for unique key and I can't turn it off because then solr says that queryelevationcomponent needs one.

Even if I add tag_id or thread_id it wont work because they got identical id. tag.id = 1 and thread.id = 1.

How should I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [UUID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) as key in your DataImportHandler query.

Comment: thx it worked.

how do one import relational tables? i have tried in vain for over 4 hours.

i have a thread table consisting of id, language_id, post_id, country_id, region_id and city_id. how should i design data-config.xml?? plz help

Comment: If it worked please at least mark it as the accepted answer. Then create other questions, one for each of your issues.

Answer (score 1):

You could prepend the table name to the key value (thread.1 , tag.1)

Comment: exactly how do you mean?
<uniqueKey>thread.1 , tag.1</uniqueKey> ?